# My terminal window is not allowing me to scroll back to lines output by my program

Tags: terminal

In the cmd window, the PowerShell window and in something I downloaded from the Windows Store called Fluent Terminal, I am unable to scroll up and see all the lines that my program outputs (it is outputting less than 9999). I have Properties->Layout->Height set to 9999 as other answers suggest, to no avail. Looking at the vertical scrollbar, it does seem ready to display a lot of lines. But when the program is run the thingy in the vertical scrollbar just moves a scosh down as program output lines scroll off above the terminal never to be seen or scrolled to again.

[image: Terminal Properties Layout settings]